# Spring STS howto add tomcat7 sources

Tags: tomcat7, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

It seems that the configuration wizard for the configuration of servers has no option of attaching sources (namely tomcat7). How can I configure the entire source code for all the used tomcat7 libs ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have launched Tomcat, there is a launch configuration generated for you. You can access this launch configuration from the "Run..." menu. Once you selected the launch configuration, there is a "Source" tab on the right where you can configure the lookup path for sources. Add the source zips of the libraries to that list and the debugger should find that.

Comment: Yeah - thx Martin, I know that. But where do I find the matching sources for the installed binaries ? The installer does not download any sources and it seems there is no available selection when installing a new server. I wonder if i really should use the ones from the tomcat download page and hope to find the matching build !?

Comment: Oh, I see... :-) There is a source code distribution download on the tomcat download page (somewhere at the bottom). It contains most (maybe not all, not sure) of the sources of the libs in the "java" folder.